# CUnit output not compliant with Jenkins Junit

Tags: testing, cunit

For a test framework with Jenkins, I am using CUnit. The result is never correct when running in Jenkins. When I inspect the output of CUnit, it is not Junit compliant. The XML file is not even XML compliant! I am using version 2.1.3. When I observe the source code, it seems the project is not finished yet for people who want Jenkins. Although Junit should be possible, there is a lot of code for another non-standard.

Does anybody have a correct version for this test tool?

Is there another tool similar to CUnit, which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

For this, I adapted C-unit. Although it is a very popular tool, the size is just 4 source files. It was easy to make this Junit compliant.

see:
https://github.com/barthoukes/cunit

The question may be closed.